# solving simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I am not understanding the general solution of the simple harmonic oscillator.

How can it get from here:

> $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x  }{\mathrm{d} t^2}=-\omega _{0}^2x$

to here:

> $x(t)=x_{0}cos(\omega_{0}t) +\frac{v_{0}}{\omega_{0}}sin(\omega_{0}t)$

I do understand that: $x(t)=Asin(\omega_{0}t-\delta)$ and $x(t)=Acos(\omega_{0}t-\phi)$ are solutions. And in this case, i can summ all the possible solutions to have the general one. But i didn't undersand where  $x_{0}$ and $\frac{v_{0}}{\omega_{0}}$ came from.

Comment: use boundary conditions

Comment: $x_0$ is the initial position, and $v_0$ is the initial velocity.

Comment: You also probably want $\omega_0^2$ in the initial differential equation you wrote.

Comment: i think some conditions are missing

Comment: Echoing what others have said, note that that $x(t)$ satisfies $x(0)=x_0$ and $x'(0)=v_0$. So presumably these conditions are present as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases}x''=-\omega^2 x \\x(0)=x_0
\\\dot{x}(0)=v_0  \end{cases}$$
The first equation is linear and has characteristic equation
$$\lambda^2=-\omega_0^2$$
with solutions $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i\omega_0$. This shows that the general solution is
$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B \sin (\omega t)$$
for some $A,B\in \mathbb R$. Imposing the conditions of the Cauchy problem yields 
$$\begin{cases}x(0)=A \cos(0)+B \sin (0)=A=x_0 \\
\dot x(0)=-\omega A \sin(0)+\omega B \cos(0)=\omega B=v_0 \end{cases}$$
so $A=x_0$, $B=\frac{v_0}{\omega}$. Hence,
$$x(t)=x_0 \cos (\omega t)+\frac{v_0}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + \omega_0^2x = 0$$

$$x(t)=e^{\lambda t} \implies e^{\lambda t}(\lambda^2 + \omega_o^2)=0\implies \lambda = \pm \omega_0 i$$

$$x(t) = A e^{\omega_0 i t} + B e^{-\omega_0 it}$$

$$e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$$

$$x(t) = A (\cos(\omega_0 t) + i\sin(\omega_0t)) + B (\cos(-\omega_0 t) + i\sin(-\omega_0t))$$

$$\cos(t) = \cos(-t) \quad\quad \sin (t) = - \sin (-t)$$

$$x(t) = A (\cos(\omega_0 t) + i\sin(\omega_0t)) + B (\cos(\omega_0 t) - i\sin(\omega_0t))$$

$$x(t) = (A+B) \cos \omega_0 t + (Ai - Bi) \sin \omega_0 t$$

$$x(t) = c_1 \cos \omega_0 t + c_2 \sin \omega_0 t$$

$$x(0) = x_0 \quad \quad x'(0) = v_0$$

$$x(0) = c_1 \cos 0 + c_2 \sin 0 \implies c_1 = x_0$$

$$x'(0) = -x_0 \omega_0 \sin 0 + c_2 \omega_0 \cos 0 \implies c_2 \omega_0 = v_0$$

$$x(t) = x_0 \cos \omega_0 t + \frac{v_0}{\omega_0} \sin \omega_0 t$$

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

$$x''(t)=-\omega_0^2x(t)$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$s^2\text{X}(s)-sx(0)-x'(0)=-\omega_0^2\text{X}(s)$$

Solving this for $\text{X}(s)$ gives us:

$$\text{X}(s)=\frac{sx(0)+x'(0)}{s^2+\omega_0^2}$$

Now, usig inverse Laplace transform, we get:

$$x(t)=x(0)\cos(\omega_0t)+\frac{x'(0)\sin(\omega_0t)}{\omega_0}$$

Comment: I didn't study Laplace transform, yet. Thank you, anyway.